# Images infinitely looping on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I am trying to achieve an effect where each image moves upwards on scroll, each image moves at different speeds and moves out of screen at the top and reappears from the bottom of the page in an infinite loop. 
Diagram below

Any examples or suggestions would be much appreciated, thank you

[image]

EDIT: https://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/BkDie

This is a perfect example however I want the scroll to be infinite and the objects to reappear from the bottom

```
$.fn.moveIt = function(){
var $window = $(window);
var instances = [];

$(this).each(function(){
instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
instances.forEach(function(inst){
  inst.update(scrollTop);
});
}, {passive: true});
}

var moveItItem = function(el){
this.el = $(el);
this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
};

moveItItem.prototype.update = function(scrollTop){
this.el.css('transform', 'translateY(' + -(scrollTop / this.speed) + 
'px)');
};

// Initialization
$(function(){
$('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt();
});
```

Comment: i think you can achieve this with css animation on translateY or top

Comment: Please show us your efforts. It will be easier to find help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a pure CSS solution to make the desired effect, which can be created using [CSS animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp). In the example below all elements are in a grid and every item has a different execution time for the same animation `gotop`.

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 5%;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.inner-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.A {
  height: auto;
  animation-name: gotop;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.B {
  height: auto;
  animation-name: gotop;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.C {
  height: auto;
  animation-name: gotop;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.D {
  height: auto;
  animation-name: gotop;
  animation-duration: 9s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes gotop {
  from {
    margin-top: 120%;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: -20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="A">
    textA
  </p>
  <p class="B">
    textB
  </p>
  <p class="C">
    textC
  </p>
  <p class="D">
    textD
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should have absolute positioning in your images.

```
<img src="..." style="position: absolute; left: XXXpx: top: YYYpx;" data-scrollamount="ZZZ" />
<img src="..." style="position: absolute; left: XXXpx: top: YYYpx;" data-scrollamount="ZZZ" />
<img src="..." style="position: absolute; left: XXXpx: top: YYYpx;" data-scrollamount="ZZZ" />
<img src="..." style="position: absolute; left: XXXpx: top: YYYpx;" data-scrollamount="ZZZ" />
.
.
.
.
```

This way you can adjust the starting position of each image. The scrollamount would also be different for each image.
Then you add an event listener for the window scroll event, . Here is some code:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    images.each(function(){
        this.style.top += this.dataset.scrollamount
    }
}
```